# OpenID Connect and Aggregated/Distributed Claims

Tags: jwt, openid-connect

I have questions concerning the aggregated and distributed claims from the [OpenID Connect Core Specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AggregatedDistributedClaims).

As I understand, those claims come from different (external) sources and as per the specification and its examples, it consists in a JWT containing claim values. I understand that this JWT is signed by the source before to be aggregated to the ID token.

Concerning aggregated Claims:

- How the RP can retrieve the public key and verify the signature of the JWT issued by the source?
- [The specification indicates](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken) `ID Tokens SHOULD NOT use the JWS or JWE x5u, x5c, jku, or jwk Header Parameter fields.`. In this particular case, is it relevant to allow one of this header to be included in the JWT header?

Distributed Claims is in fact just a link and optionally an access token to retrieve the claims.

- Is there any reason to allow only Bearer tokens? Why can't we use other token types such as MAC or POP tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the current distributed claim specification does not fully address the issue of key discovery for the claims issuer. It assumes a security / trust assumption that distributed claim providers are previously known to the relying party (i.e., closed federation model).

Comment: After all, this is the best answer for these questions. There should be a high level of trust between the ID provider and the sub-IDP.

Answer (score 0):

> How the RP can retrieve the public key and verify the signature of the JWT issued by the source?

Assuming the external sources are just other OIDC Providers, their public keys may be obtained via [OIDC Discovery](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html) - see section 4.2, parameter "jwks_uri".

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the RP does not know the OIDC provider that issued the aggregated JWT.

Comment: Yes, the spec leaves unspecified how you can trust the keys. Signatures provide no security value if you inspect the message you want to verify (i.e., the JWT) to find which keys to use to verify it (jwks_uri).